# fancyhdr does nothing

Tags: fancyhdr

I am trying to move the page number to the topic right corner of the page and remove it from the bottom center using `fancyhdr`. After reading the `fancyhdr` syntax it seems fairly intuitive, yet when I compile my code nothing happens. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{This is my name}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{center of the footer!}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\doublespacing

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
    \vspace*{1cm}
       \textbf{title}
%       \vspace{0.5cm}
%        Thesis Subtitle

\vspace{7cm}
by \\
Name 

\vfill
  A thesis \\
  submitted in partial fulfillment \\
 of the requirements for the degree of \\
 Masters of Science in Economics \\
       \vspace{2cm}
       May 2020


\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\chapter*{Copyright or Creative Commons}
\pagestyle{empty}

\chapter*{Electronic Defense Committee Approval}
\pagestyle{empty}

\chapter*{Dedication}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}

\chapter*{Abstract}
Abstract goes here

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\listoffigures


\begin{abbreviations}{ll}
\end{abbreviations}

\chapter*{List of Symbols}

\chapter{Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

intro

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try to change the lines ``\pagestyle{empty}`` to ``\thispagestyle{empty}``.

Comment: @Vincent is correct.